# python class AttributeError

Tags: python, oop

The purpose of this script is:

•   Read a group of csv files.

•   Scrape the date and extract some features out of it.

•   Merge these csv files into a single data frame.

•   Import the final data frame into another class and print it.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


class DataSource:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dfs = []
        self.final = pd.DataFrame()
        self.names = ['Date', 'Time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'Volume']
        self.directory = os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\forex")

    def merge(self):
        for file in os.listdir(self.directory):
            df = pd.read_csv(file, names=self.names,
                             parse_dates={'Release Date': ['Date', 'Time']})
            self.dfs.append(df)

        self.final = pd.concat(self.dfs, axis=0)
        self.final = self.final[['Release Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]
        print(self.final.head())
        return self.final


class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = DataSource.final

    def print(self):
        return print(self.df.head())

x = test()
x.print()
```

Here is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/hello.py", line 31, in 
    x = test()

File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/project/hello.py", line 26, in **init**
    self.df = DataSource.final

AttributeError: type object 'DataSource' has no attribute 'final'

Comment: Yeah, `final` is an *instance attribute*, not a class attribute. `DataSource().final` would work for example…

Comment: You haven't initialized a Datasource instance. `final` belongs to an instance, not the class. (It is inside the `init`) Therefore you cannot access `final` without initializing an instance of `Datasource`. That said, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve with the `test` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cannot access `self.final` property directly in your DataSource class. You need to instantiate it first. So your `test` class will more be like :

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = DataSource()
        self.df = self.d.merge()
    def print(self):
        return print(self.df.head())
```